# How to Deploy a Laravel Application to Amazon Web Server AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

I already have a PHP website running under /var/www/html root location, and now I would like to deploy a Laravel application in /var/www/html/sales folder. I have installed Composer and cloned Laravel GitHub repository in /var/www/html/sales folder, but when I type www.domain.com/sales/public it says the site is not reachable whereas if I type www.domain.com, my other PHP website is working fine.

What am I missing? Can anyone please help me with this?